# Normalization / Subobjects in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Bit new to Mongodb, have a question on how to store data properly.

I'm making a domain search / history POC, and unsure how to store data. If it was mySQL I'd have the following tables

Domain - Domain name, and current status
Domain_Updates - Foreign key to Domain, would store the whois information

```
{
   domain: 'blah.com',
   status: 'registered',
   updates: [
       {
           owner: 'john smith',
           status: 'expiration',
           date: somedategoeshere
       },
       {
           status: 'available',
           date:'somedategoeshere'
       }
   ]
}
```

Would this format of MongoDB last if there were hundreds, or thousands of updates per domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on if you wish to search through the updates field quickly. . . are you planning to index it? 
If you are, the entirety of the updates[] array ends up in the index.

> ```
> Multikey Index
>
> MongoDB uses multikey indexes to index the content stored in arrays.
> ```
>
> If you index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB
>   creates separate index entries for every element of the array. These
>   multikey indexes allow queries to select documents that contain arrays
>   by matching on element or elements of the arrays. MongoDB
>   automatically determines whether to create a multikey index if the
>   indexed field contains an array value; you do not need to explicitly
>   specify the multikey type

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/

If you're interested in flatter indexing (probably) then you'd be best served injecting a domain_key into the update document and store them in a separate collection.

Comment: I think going with the second solution sounds best to me. Multiple collections using a "foreign key" (injecting domain_key). Thank ye kindly

Comment: Varun Jain Note that this relational approach will force you to do joins manually. And if you have lots of this kind of stuff in your app, either you better design your schema in 'no-sql way', i.e. embedded and denormalized, or use relational sql database. The answer is not that simple and I suggest you to read various 'mongodb schema design' topics, there are plenty of them.